# XML Parsing Error: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am parsing an RSS feed from the following URL:

http://rss.sciam.com/ScientificAmerican-Global?format=xml

```
// $xml_text is filled with the contents read from the URL
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
$res = xml_parse($xml_parser, $xml_text);

if (!$res) {
  $error =
    xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)).
    " at line ".
    xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser);
}

// $error contains: "SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing at line 1"
```

[FeedValidator.org](http://FeedValidator.org) says this is a good feed.

How can I get PHP's XML parser to work around this error?

**EDIT**: It looks like they are redirecting this feed to another location based on the user-agent.  My PHP script is not getting the correct feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works for me, you must be getting the text wrong.